# Stash-git pull issue

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-stash

We are using Stash for our SCM. Currently we are a team of three (developer1,developer2,developer3). Developer1 is working on branch1 of a stash repository. He has pushed some changes on branch1  which I am also working.I want to pull the branch1 data from remote server to my working copy.

But pull get aborted because I have my local changes via 'source tree tool'. How can I keep my local changes and pull the data from remote server without overwriting it? I want to push the local changes to remote afterwards as latest commit.

Please help.

Comment: Not confuse you, but you could use `git stash` (not the same as Stash) for your current work, then pull, then apply the stash.  This is similar to doing a merge from the remote into your local branch.  You could also commit your work locally and then rebase on the remote.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Any idea on how can I achieve this via 'source tree'?

Comment: Either of the answers given below should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git stash` to stash your local changes. This will set your branch pointing to last commit from remote. Then do `git pull` to get latest changes. This will pull his changes to your local. Now if you want to write changes that you made (you just stashed them), use `git stash apply` to apply your changes on top of latest changes.

Comment: Thanks Hyder. I have few clarifications though. Will "git stash apply" merge my changes to the latest data pulled(which is pushed by developer1)? Should I have to do perform a "git push" again to make my changes reflected in remote? Sorry am very new to Stash/git.

Comment: yes. git stash apply will apply your earlier stashed changes to your local branch. Then you need to do 1. git add -A 2. git commit -m "<commit message>" 3. git push. This will push your changes to remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

If your current changes are complete enough for a commit, then go ahead and commit them *before* you pull. Then when you pull git will merge your changes with the other developer and create a new commit with those merged changes. Then go ahead and push.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your instructions.